# How to add a for loop inside .join() in python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, join

I have found people doing something similar to this one in codewars. But for me somehow it never works. Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this code and what I should do to correct it. 
Thank you in advance!

P.S.:I know that writing a for loop outside solves this but I want my code to be neat and concise :D
Edit: Thank you guys. It worked!

```py
names = ["Alexa","Siri","Cortana"]
print(" ".join("Hello there ",(i for i in names)))
```

Here is the fixed code:

```py
names = ["Alexa","Siri","Cortana"]
print("".join([f"Hello there {i}!\n" for i in names]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a for loop, this is a generator expression (in your case) or list/dict/set comprehension. Second, `str.join` takes only one argument and you provided two - did you want your output to be: `Hello there Alexa Hello there Siri Hello there Cortana` or `Hello there Alexa Siri Cortana` ? Depending on the answer, the code could be:

```
print(" ".join("Hello there " + x for x in names))
```

or

```
print("Hello there " + " ".join(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
names = ["Alexa","Siri","Cortana"]

print(', '.join(['Hello there ' + i for i in names]))
```

Output: -

```
'Hello there Alexa,  Hello there Siri,  Hello there Cortana'
```

Comment: If you want the correct amount of commas, put the comma in the joining string: `', '.join`

Comment: And remove the other comma.

Comment: Maybe you know, but I have to mention that `str.join`  is faster with a list comprehension than a generator expression, +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the value into the string which is being joined:

```
names = ["Alexa","Siri","Cortana"]
print(" ".join(f"Hello there {i}" for i in names))
```

Output:

```
Hello there Alexa Hello there Siri Hello there Cortana
```